# How can I branch out multiple API calls from the result of one API call and collect them after all are finished with Combine?

Tags: ios, swift, combine

So, I have this sequence of API calls, where I fetch a employee details, then fetch the company and project details that the employee is associated with. After both fetching are complete, I combine both and publish a fetchCompleted event. I've isolated the relevant code below.

```
func getUserDetails() -> AnyPublisher<UserDetails, Error>
func getCompanyDetails(user: UserDetails) -> AnyPublisher<CompanyDetails, Error>
func getProjectDetails(user: UserDetails) -> AnyPublisher<ProjectDetails, Error>
```

If I do this,

```
func getCompleteUserDetails() -> AnyPublisher<UserFetchState, Never> {

  let cvs = CurrentValueSubject<UserFetchState, Error>(.initial)

  let companyPublisher = getUserDetails()
    .flatMap { getCompanyDetails($0) }
  let projectPublisher = getUserDetails()
    .flatMap { getProjectDetails($0) }
  
  companyPublisher.combineLatest(projectPublisher)
    .sink { cvs.send(.fetchComplete) }
  return cvs.eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

getUserDetails() will get called twice. What I need is fetch the userDetails once and with that, branch the stream into two, map it to fetch the company details and project details and re-combine both.
Is there a elegant(flatter) way to do the following.

```
func getCompleteUserDetails() -> AnyPublisher<UserFetchState, Never> {

  let cvs = CurrentValueSubject<UserFetchState, Error>(.initial)

    getUserDetails()
      .sink {
        let companyPublisher = getCompanyDetails($0)
        let projectPublisher = getProjectDetails($0)
        
        companyPublisher.combineLatest(projectPublisher)
          .sink { cvs.send(.fetchComplete) }
      }
  return cvs.eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of branching the stream into two? There is no need to branch and then later recombine. Do the first publisher, then flat map and do the second publisher, then end.

Comment: @matt Can you give an simple example? I do not understand which first publisher you mean.

Comment: Get the user. Pass the user into a flatmap and inside the flatmap make a publisher that _zips_ the company fetcher and the project fetcher and outputs user, company, and project. Now just stop, let the output be the signal.

Comment: @matt ok, that works grea. I think I had misunderstood what zip/ combine does. Still learning Combine. Thanks

Comment: What I would actually do is zip the company publisher and the project publisher _and_ a Just that publishes the incoming user, so that all three pieces of info pass down the pipeline.

Comment: I teach it to you here: https://www.apeth.com/UnderstandingCombine/

Comment: Thanks, @matt for all the help. I will need to check it out.

Answer (score 2):

The whole idea of Combine is that you construct a *pipeline* down which data flows. Actually what flows down can be a value or a completion, where a completion could be a failure (error). So:

- You do not need to *make* a signal that the pipeline has produced its value; the arrival of that value at the end of the pipeline *is* that signal.
- Similarly, you do not need to *make* a signal that the pipeline's work has completed; a publisher that has produced all the values it is going to produce produces the completion signal automatically, so the arrival of that completion at the end of the pipeline *is* that signal.

After all, when you receive a letter, the post office doesn't call you up on the phone and say, "You've got mail." Rather, the postman hands you *the letter*. You don't need to be *told* you've received a letter; you simply *receive* it.

---

Okay, let's demonstrate. The key to understanding your own pipeline is simply to track what kind of value is traveling down it at any given juncture. So let's construct a model pipeline that does the sort of thing you need done. I will posit three types of value:

```
struct User {
}
struct Project {
}
struct Company {
}
```

And I will imagine that it is possible to go online and fetch all of that information: the User independently, and the Project and Company based on information contained in the User. I will simulate that by providing utility functions that return publishers for each type of information; in real life these would probably be deferred futures, but I will simply use Just to keep things simple:

```
func makeUserFetcherPublisher() -> AnyPublisher<User,Error> {
    Just(User()).setFailureType(to: Error.self).eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
func makeProjectFetcherPublisher(user:User) -> AnyPublisher<Project,Error> {
    Just(Project()).setFailureType(to: Error.self).eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
func makeCompanyFetcherPublisher(user:User) -> AnyPublisher<Company,Error> {
    Just(Company()).setFailureType(to: Error.self).eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Now then, let's construct our pipeline. I take it that our goal is to produce, as the final value in the pipeline, *all* the information we have collected: the User, the Project, and the Company. So our final output will be a *tuple* of those three things. (Tuples are *important* when you are doing Combine stuff. Passing a tuple down the pipeline is extremely common.)

Okay, let's get started. In the beginning there is nothing, so we need an initial publisher to kick off the process. That will be our user fetcher:

```
let myWonderfulPipeline = self.makeUserFetcherPublisher()
```

What's coming out the end of that pipeline is a User. We now want to feed that User into the next two publishers, fetching the corresponding Project and Company. The way to insert a publisher into the middle of a pipeline is with `flatMap`. And remember, our goal is to produce the tuple of all our info. So:

```
let myWonderfulPipeline = self.makeUserFetcherPublisher()
    // at this point, the value is a User
    .flatMap { (user:User) -> AnyPublisher<(User,Project,Company), Error> in
        // ?
    }
    // at this point, the value is a tuple: (User,Project,Company)
```

So what goes into `flatMap`, where the question mark is? Well, we must produce a *publisher* that produces the tuple we have promised. The tuple-making publisher par excellence is Zip. We have three values in our tuple, so this is a Zip3:

```
let myWonderfulPipeline = self.makeUserFetcherPublisher()
    .flatMap { (user:User) -> AnyPublisher<(User,Project,Company), Error> in
        // ?
        let result = Publishers.Zip3(/* ? */)
        return result.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
```

So what are we zipping? We must zip *publishers*. Well, we know two of those publishers — they are the publishers we have already defined!

```
let myWonderfulPipeline = self.makeUserFetcherPublisher()
    .flatMap { (user:User) -> AnyPublisher<(User,Project,Company), Error> in
        let pub1 = self.makeProjectFetcherPublisher(user: user)
        let pub2 = self.makeCompanyFetcherPublisher(user: user)
        // ?
        let result = Publishers.Zip3(/* ? */, pub1, pub2)
        return result.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
```

We're almost done! What goes in the missing slot? Remember, it must be a *publisher*. And what's our goal? We want to pass on the *very same User* that arrived from upstream. And what's the publisher that does that? It's Just! So:

```
let myWonderfulPipeline = self.makeUserFetcherPublisher()
    .flatMap { (user:User) -> AnyPublisher<(User,Project,Company), Error> in
        let pub1 = self.makeProjectFetcherPublisher(user: user)
        let pub2 = self.makeCompanyFetcherPublisher(user: user)
        let just = Just(user).setFailureType(to:Error.self)
        let result = Publishers.Zip3(just, pub1, pub2)
        return result.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
```

And we're done. No muss no fuss. This is a pipeline that produces a `(User,Project,Company)` tuple. Whoever subscribes to this pipeline does not need some extra signal; the arrival of the tuple *is* the signal. And now the subscriber can do something with that info. Let's create the subscriber:

```
myWonderfulPipeline.sink {
    completion in
    if case .failure(let error) = completion {
        print("error:", error)
    }
} receiveValue: {
    user, project, company in
    print(user, project, company)
}.store(in: &self.storage)
```

We didn't do anything very interesting — we simply printed the tuple contents. But you see, in real life the subscriber would now do something useful with that data.

Comment: This is beautifully explained. Thanks for the very detailed explanation Matt. . Many a times in the pipeline, I'd just use a map/ flatmap to transform elements from the upstream, but I'd want the original element after the transformation for some other operation, which is what happened and which is why I thought of "branching the stream" to transform them seperately and recombine.

Comment: I understand the temptation to "split and join", but in my limited experience it is never right. :) The way to pass all the info down the pipeline is to keep passing all the info down the pipeline. If this means that "extra" info has to pass through some of the operators unused in order to get where it needs to go, so be it. That's better than thinking one can shunt a copy of the info round the side. The pipeline I've constructed in my demo above is much simpler and easier to construct and understand than what you were trying to do...!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `zip` operator to get a `Publisher` which emits a value whenever both of its upstreams emitted a value and hence `zip` together `getCompanyDetails` and `getProjectDetails`.

You also don't need a `Subject` to signal the fetch being finished, you can just call `map` on the `flatMap`.

```
func getCompleteUserDetails() -> AnyPublisher<UserFetchState, Error> {
    getUserDetails()
        .flatMap { getCompanyDetails(user: $0).zip(getProjectDetails(user: $0)) }
        .map { _ in UserFetchState.fetchComplete }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

However, you shouldn't need a `UserFetchState` to signal the state of your pipeline (and especially shouldn't throw away the fetched `CompanyDetails` and `ProjectDetails` objects in the middle of your pipeline. You should simply return the fetched `CompanyDetails` and `ProjectDetails` as a result of your `flatMap`.

```
func getCompleteUserDetails() -> AnyPublisher<(CompanyDetails, ProjectDetails), Error> {
    getUserDetails()
        .flatMap { getCompanyDetails(user: $0).zip(getProjectDetails(user: $0)) }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Comment: But now you've thrown away all the fetched data. Tell the OP to pass the data out of the pipeline. You don't send another signal, the output is the signal.